# How can I re-format my code so that it uses object-oriented programming?

Tags: python, oop

So, I learned the basics of the pygame module by making a hangman program, from a tutorial by tech with tim. The way he coded it he did it without using classes and stuff like that, because it was meant for beginners. Because of that, I had to do some really weird things in my code that I never had to do before.

So, I added some stuff to the hangman game, with the same non-OOP approach.

Now, I realize that the weird comprises I had to make came from the fact that I didn't use a OOP approach to develop this hangman game with.

I'd like some guidance on how to take this mess and convert into an OOP-based code.

```
import os

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

import pygame
import math
import random

# Adjustments
"""
1. Change source of words, from taking fromlist to reading from .txt file
2. Add hints (for words of 7+ letters)
3. Add a Main Menu to the game.
4. (if possible), add "twisted" logic option.
5. (if possible), change the aesthetics of the program.
"""
# setup display
pygame.init()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Twisted Hangman!")

# button variables
RADIUS = 20
GAP = 15
letters = []  # p34, 36, "A", True]
startx = round((WIDTH - (RADIUS * 2 + GAP) * 13) / 2)
starty = 400
A = 65

#for-loop to create a list of lists. E.g.: letters = [ [1, 5, 'A', True], [10, 50, 'C', False], [65, 200, 'D', True]]
#a single element of letters is a list containing 4 elements - x and y coordinates, an actual letter, and a boolean value that determines letter visibility.
#the x,y, and bool elements are important later on in rendering a button of the letter 'A' at coordinates 1,5,
# or at preventing the rendering of button 'C' at coordinates 10,50.
for i in range(26):
    x = startx + GAP * 2 + ((RADIUS * 2 + GAP) * (i % 13))
    y = starty + ((i // 13) * (GAP + RADIUS * 2))
    letters.append([x, y, chr(A + i), True])

# fonts
LETTER_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('times', 25)
COUNTER_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('times', 20)
WORD_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('times', 50)
TITLE_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('times', 70)

# load images with list comprehension
images = [pygame.image.load("hangman" + str(i) + ".png") for i in range(7)]

# game variables
hangman_status = 0
hangman_flag = [0]
words = []
with open('words.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            word.upper()
            words.append(word)
        # words = ["COMPUTER", "SCIENCE", "PYTHON", "SNAKE"]
word = random.choice(words)
guessed = []

# colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = ((0, 255, 0))

# setup Game Loop
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True


def draw():
    win.fill(WHITE)

    # draw title
    text = TITLE_FONT.render("TWISTED HANGMAN", 1, BLACK)
    win.blit(text, (WIDTH / 2 - text.get_width() / 2, 20))

    #draw letter counter 
    counter = "letter count: " + str(len(word))
    text = COUNTER_FONT.render(counter, 1, BLACK)
    win.blit(text, (150,310))

    # draw word
    display_word = ""
    for letter in word:
        if letter in guessed:
            display_word += letter + " "
        else:
            display_word += "_ "
    text = WORD_FONT.render(display_word, 1, BLACK)
    win.blit(text, (375, 200))
    
    if len(word) >= 7:
        if hangman_flag[0] == 1:
            rdm_ltr = random.choice(word)
            guessed.append(rdm_ltr)
            display_word = ""
            for letter in word:
                if letter in guessed:
                    display_word += letter + " "
                else:
                    display_word += "_ "
            text = WORD_FONT.render(display_word, 1, BLACK)
            win.blit(text, (375, 200))
            hangman_flag[0] *= 0
            #make rdm_ltr's visible value to False
            for letter in letters:
                if rdm_ltr == letter[2]:
                    letter[3] = False
    # draw buttons
    for letter in letters:
        x, y, ltr, visible = letter  # splitting off the variable [x, y, ltr]
        if visible:
            pygame.draw.circle(win, BLACK, (x, y), RADIUS, 3)
            text = LETTER_FONT.render(ltr, 1, BLACK)  # render text
            win.blit(text,
                     (x - text.get_width() / 2, y - text.get_height() / 2))

    win.blit(images[hangman_status], (150, 100))
    pygame.display.update()


def display_message(message):
    pygame.time.delay(1000)
    win.fill(WHITE)
    text = WORD_FONT.render(message, 1, BLACK)
    win.blit(
        text,
        (WIDTH / 2 - text.get_width() / 2, HEIGHT / 2 - text.get_height() / 2))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(3000)


def main():
    global hangman_status

    FPS = 60
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True

    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                for letter in letters:
                    x, y, ltr, visible = letter
                    if visible:
                        dis = math.sqrt((x - mouse_x) ** 2 + (y - mouse_y) ** 2)
                        if dis < RADIUS:
                            letter[3] = False
                            guessed.append(ltr)
                            if ltr not in word:
                                hangman_status += 1

        draw()

        won = True
        for letter in word:
            if letter not in guessed:
                won = False
                break

        if won:
            display_message("YOU WON!")
            break

        if hangman_status == 6:
            display_message("YOU LOST!")
            break
    reset_game()


def reset_game():
    global hangman_status
    global hangman_flag
    global word
    global guessed
    global letters
    global i
    global x
    global y
    hangman_status = 0
    word = random.choice(words)
    guessed = []
    letters = []
    for i in range(26):
        x = startx + GAP * 2 + ((RADIUS * 2 + GAP) * (i % 13))
        y = starty + ((i // 13) * (GAP + RADIUS * 2))
        letters.append([x, y, chr(A + i), True])
    if len(word) >= 7:
       hangman_flag[0] = 1


def main_menu():
    play_game = True
    while play_game:
        win.fill(WHITE)
        text = TITLE_FONT.render("Click Mouse Button to Play", 1, BLACK)
        win.blit(text, (WIDTH / 2 - text.get_width() / 2, 200))
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                play_game = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                main()
    pygame.quit()

main_menu()
```

Comment: My advice would be to start by breaking your functions into smaller logical units, especially your draw() function which does a lot of things that themselves can also be abstracted into functions (e.g. draw title, draw..).

Comment: thanks. i think my biggest confusion is what i should make as a class and what should be the attributes for that class...

Comment: If i was looking for a Hangman library, I'd expect a class to represent the Hangman game state, which I can initiate by giving it word, can ask it to test a letter and ask it to return the current solved letters, with spaces, ask it how many lives it has left, and what letters are left to try. I think that's about it!  So I think a 'Hangman' class that does those would be a good place to start.

Comment: but I would specifically not have anything in Hangman which has anything to do with the screen layout, printing to the screen etc.  (e.g. your letters might be in there, but physical spacing between the letters should not be,  and you may return a list of found letters and spaces, but wouldn't print them in the class)